# Список стран для listview

Tags: android, listview

Есть ли у вас готовый список стран мира для `ListView` если есть то поделитесь пожалуйста или скажите где его можно достать.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: Мне нужен для ListView Android

Comment: В чем сложность взять список и заполнить?

Answer (score 2):

```
<item>Абхазия</item>
<item>Австралия</item>
<item>Австрия</item>
<item>Азербайджан</item>
<item>Албания</item>
<item>Алжир</item>
<item>Ангола</item>
<item>Андорра</item>
<item>Антигуа и Барбуда</item>
<item>Аргентина</item>
<item>Армения</item>
<item>Афганистан</item>
<item>Багамские Острова</item>
<item>Бангладеш</item>
<item>Барбадос</item>
<item>Бахрейн</item>
<item>Беларусь</item>
<item>Белиз</item>
<item>Бельгия</item>
<item>Бенин</item>
<item>Болгария</item>
<item>Боливия</item>
<item>Босния и Герцеговина</item>
<item>Ботсвана</item>
<item>Бразилия</item>
<item>Бруней</item>
<item>Буркина Фасо</item>
<item>Бурунди</item>
<item>Бутан</item>
<item>Вануату</item>
<item>Ватикан</item>
<item>Великобритания</item>
<item>Венгрия</item>
<item>Венесуэла</item>
<item>Восточный Тимоp</item>
<item>Вьетнам</item>
<item>Габон</item>
<item>Гаити</item>
<item>Гайана</item>
<item>Гамбия</item>
<item>Гана</item>
<item>Гватемала</item>
<item>Гвинея</item>
<item>Гвинея-Бисау</item>
<item>Германия</item>
<item>Гондурас</item>
<item>Гренада</item>
<item>Греция</item>
<item>Грузия</item>
<item>Дания</item>
<item>Демократическая Республика Конго</item>
<item>Джибути</item>
<item>Доминиканская Республика</item>
<item>Доминикана</item>
<item>Египет</item>
<item>Замбия</item>
<item>Зимбабве</item>
<item>Израиль</item>
<item>Индия</item>
<item>Индонезия</item>
<item>Иордания</item>
<item>Ирак</item>
<item>Иран</item>
<item>Ирландия</item>
<item>Исландия</item>
<item>Испания</item>
<item>Италия</item>
<item>Йемен</item>
<item>Кабо-Верде</item>
<item>Казахстан</item>
<item>Камбоджа</item>
<item>Камерун</item>
<item>Канада</item>
<item>Катар</item>
<item>Кения</item>
<item>Кипр</item>
<item>Киргизия</item>
<item>Кирибати</item>
<item>Китай</item>
<item>Колумбия</item>
<item>Коморские острова</item>
<item>КНДР</item>
<item>Коста-Рика</item>
<item>Кот-д’Ивуар</item>
<item>Куба</item>
<item>Кувейт</item>
<item>Лаос</item>
<item>Латвия</item>
<item>Лесото</item>
<item>Либерия</item>
<item>Ливан</item>
<item>Ливия</item>
<item>Литва</item>
<item>Лихтенштейн</item>
<item>Люксембург</item>
<item>Маврикий</item>
<item>Мавритания</item>
<item>Мадагаскар</item>
<item>Македония</item>
<item>Малави</item>
<item>Малайзия</item>
<item>Мали</item>
<item>Мальдивы</item>
<item>Мальта</item>
<item>Марокко</item>
<item>Маршалловы Острова</item>
<item>Мексика</item>
<item>Микронезия</item>
<item>Мозамбик</item>
<item>Молдова</item>
<item>Монако</item>
<item>Монголия</item>
<item>Мьянма</item>
<item>Намибия</item>
<item>Науру</item>
<item>Непал</item>
<item>Нигер</item>
<item>Нигерия</item>
<item>Нидерланды</item>
<item>Никарагуа</item>
<item>Новая Зеландия</item>
<item>Норвегия</item>
<item>ОАЭ</item>
<item>Оман</item>
<item>Пакистан</item>
<item>Палау</item>
<item>Панама</item>
<item>Папуа-Новая Гвинея</item>
<item>Парагвай</item>
<item>Перу</item>
<item>Польша</item>
<item>Португалия</item>
<item>Республика Конго</item>
<item>Республика Корея</item>
<item>Россия</item>
<item>Руанда</item>
<item>Румыния</item>
<item>Сальвадор</item>
<item>Самоа</item>
<item>Сан-Марино</item>
<item>Сан-Томе и Принсипи</item>
<item>Саудовская Аравия</item>
<item>Свазиленд</item>
<item>Северные Марианские острова</item>
<item>Сейшелы</item>
<item>Сенегал</item>
<item>Сент-Винсент и Гренадины</item>
<item>Сент-Китс и Невис</item>
<item>Сент-Люсия</item>
<item>Сербия</item>
<item>Сингапур</item>
<item>Сирия</item>
<item>Словакия</item>
<item>Словения</item>
<item>Соединённые Штаты Америки</item>
<item>Соломоновы Острова</item>
<item>Сомали</item>
<item>Судан</item>
<item>Сьерра-Леоне</item>
<item>Таджикистан</item>
<item>Таиланд</item>
<item>Танзания</item>
<item>Того</item>
<item>Тонга</item>
<item>Тринидад и Тобаго</item>
<item>Тувалу</item>
<item>Тунис</item>
<item>Туркмения</item>
<item>Турция</item>
<item>Уганда</item>
<item>Узбекистан</item>
<item>Украина</item>
<item>Уругвай</item>
<item>Фиджи</item>
<item>Филиппины</item>
<item>Финляндия</item>
<item>Франция</item>
<item>Хорватия</item>
<item>Центральноафриканская Республика</item>
<item>Чад</item>
<item>Черногория</item>
<item>Чехия</item>
<item>Чили</item>
<item>Швейцария</item>
<item>Швеция</item>
<item>Шри-Ланка</item>
<item>Эквадор</item>
<item>Экваториальная Гвинея</item>
<item>Эритрея</item>
<item>Эстония</item>
<item>Эфиопия</item>
<item>Южно-Африканская Республика</item>
<item>Южный Судан</item>
<item>Ямайка</item>
<item>Япония</item>
```

Comment: `<item>Страны Африки:</item>` какая интересная страна. А за Вашу сортировку пользователи будут долго говорить Вам "спасибо"

Comment: Я потом отдельно просортировал в Android Studio